# How do I have friends time on Facebook not shown

Tags: facebook, time-tracker

Friends are listed to right of Facebook page. Next to their names is the amount of time
they spent on Facebook. How do I not show that information?

Answer (score 1):

The time shown is not how long they've been on Facebook, it's how long since they were last on Facebook, and generally shows against the Mobile icon.

The list of friends on the right of your Facebook page is only there is your browser is wide enough. make your browser window narrower and it will not be shown.